# CVXPY: suppress output for GLPK

Tags: glpk, cvxpy

I am using cvxpy and since the update to 1.0.6 I get unwanted output when calling GLPK.

```
import cvxpy as cvx
x = cvx.Variable(2)
p = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(x[0]), [x[0] + x[1] == 1, x[0] - x[1] >= 1])
p.solve(solver = cvx.GLPK)
```

In IPython3 this creates the output

```
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.61
2 rows, 2 columns, 4 non-zeros
      0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   2.000e+00 (2)
      1: obj =   1.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
*     2: obj =   1.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Out[5]: 1.0
```

In 0.4.11 I only got the `1.0` printed and I would like to have back this behaviour.
For other solvers, there is the `verbose` option, but for GLPK this does not change anything. Both yield the same output.

```
p.solve(solver = cvx.GLPK, verbose = False)
p.solve(solver = cvx.GLPK, verbose = True)
```

Any idea, how to stop the output?

PS: I want to use the simplex method. If another solver provides this, that would be a workaround.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?